# How do I find if a value is present in a value list in dictionary?

Tags: python

So here is the question. I am trying to find if a particular value is part of a value list in a dictionary. when I tried using `.values()`, it wouldn't work. Here is the code. The part indicated does not go into the `if` statement.

```
company_dict = dict()

while True:
    command = input()
    if command == 'End':
        break

    (employer,id_worker) = command.split(' -> ')

    if id_worker in company_dict.values():  # THIS
        continue                            # PART
    else:
        if employer not in company_dict:
            company_dict[employer] = []
        company_dict[employer].append(id_worker)
```

And here is how I have managed to solve it, but it is extremely inefficient:

```
while True:
    flag = 0
    command = input()
    if command == 'End':
        break

    (employer,id_worker) = command.split(' -> ')
    for key,values in company_dict.items():
        for i in values:
            if id_worker == i and employer == key:
                flag = 1

    if flag == 1:
        continue
    else:
        if employer not in company_dict:
            company_dict[employer] = []
        company_dict[employer].append(id_worker)
```

Comment: You say it's extremely inefficient, but in terms of time complexity, that's the best you can expect. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: "..it wouldnt work" Please explain more details. Dooes the program output an error? What didn't work? Explain the use case. Which Python version?

Comment: In what way does the part indicated not go into the `if` statement?

Answer (score 0):

This will print 'True' if the key exists in the dictionary. It's basically the same as what you had and it should work fine, check to see if it prints 'True'

```py
company_dict = dict()
 
while True:
    command = input("employer -> worker_id")
    if command.lower() == 'end':
        break
 
    employer, id_worker = command.split(' -> ')
 
    if id_worker in company_dict.values():
        print(True)
        continue
    else:
        if not company_dict.get(employer, false):
            company_dict[employer] = [worker_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `break` from the `for` loop if you find a match, and then use an `else` after the `for` loop to mean execute some code if the `for` loop reached the end without `break`.

```
while True:
    command = input()
    if command == 'End':
        break

    (employer,id_worker) = command.split(' -> ')
    for key,values in company_dict.items():
        if employer == key and id_worker in values:
            break
    else:
        if employer not in company_dict:
            company_dict[employer] = []
        company_dict[employer].append(id_worker)
```

This will be more efficient than what you have, because you stop searching after the first match -- both due to the `break` from the explicit loop and the fact that the expression `id_worker in values` will stop iterating on the first match.  (Here the use of `in` for inclusion testing also avoids using an explicit loop for the iteration over `values`, so may be a bit faster for that reason also.)